# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined."

Tags: javascript, arrays

This program should print out the arrays.

But why am I getting

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

I am new to learning JavaScript. Thank you.

```js
const animearray= [
    ["mursalin",'tuly','ahad'],
    ['eren','luffy','minato'],
    ['asif','sara','rakib']

]

for (let i=0;i<=animearray.length;i++){
    const rows = animearray[i];
    for (let j=0;j<=rows.length; j++){
        console.log(rows[j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Change `<=` to `<` in both cases, since array index starts at 0 and ends at length-1

Answer (score 5):

```
for (let i=0;i<=animearray.length;i++)
```

Since arrays are indexed from **0** to **length-1**, where **length** is the number of elements in the array, the program is throwing an error when **i** equals the array length. Iterating upto **animearray.length-1** would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating for an extra element you have initialized the **I=0** and loop is running **4 times** which means checking **0,1,2,3** where on **3rd iteration** it is not finding anything

```js
const animearray= [
    ["mursalin",'tuly','ahad'],
    ['eren','luffy','minato'],
    ['asif','sara','rakib'],

]

for (let i=0;i<=animearray.length-1;i++){
    const rows = animearray[i];
    for (let j=0;j<=rows.length-1; j++){
        console.log(rows[j]);
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const animearray = [
    ["mursalin", 'tuly', 'ahad'],
    ['eren', 'luffy', 'minato'],
    ['asif', 'sara', 'rakib']
]

animearray.forEach(function(e) {
    e.forEach(function(a) {
        console.log(a);
    });
});
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i < animearray.length; i++) {
  const rows = animearray[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    console.log(rows[j]);
  }
}
```

but if you want to loop through array or multidimensional array then you can use forEach loop also

```js
    animearray.forEach(function (e) {
      e.forEach(function (a) {
        console.log(a);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your code, it really helps others to understand the solution.

Comment: I added forEach option also